# How to write generic regular expression for id's like ID_FILE_NEW?

Tags: regex

The file contain lines like,

```
MENUITEM "&New\tCtrl+N",                ID_FILE_NEW
MENUITEM "Recent File",                 ID_FILE_MRU_FILE1, GRAYED
```

So i want the output as below

```
ID_FILE_NEW
ID_FILE_MRU_FILE1
```

as well as there is possibility that file contains id's as below

```
ID_VIEW_STATUS_BAR
ID_VIEW_STATUS_BAR_......_N nth number of text after "_"
```

so how to write generic regular expression to get all of these id's from file?

Comment: Please provide us more information...

Answer (score 0):

`/\w*_\w*_\w*/g`

have a look on
[Cheatsheet for the regularexpression](https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/)

Comment: so if the id is like ID_FILE_NEW_OPEN_CLOSE, so i have to write regex like /\w*_\w*_\w*_\w*_\w*/g but i don't want to write  " _ "  this in regex. if there is n number of occurences  " _ "  in id then what is the generic regex expression?

Comment: which programming language you using ??

Comment: Perl programming language.